Exclude CMD results from Windows search menu?
when I search for instance 'notepad' or 'explorer' in windows Start Menu I get duplicate results. One being the app that, when clicking open file location, leads to the Apps shell menu, and the other leading to the exact location of the executable.
There are already exclusions for these folders in indexing options, so I've found out this is probably due to the CMD functionality in windows search (The second result only shows up when I type the full program name).
Now, this duplicate result is only a minor annoyance, but I feel like this could be disabled, and I never use this feature anyways. How can I turn off CMD functionality in Windows start menu, so that I won't get any of these results? I can't find any windows settings related to CMD in search.
